# Cross Browser Testing with Allure report

Tags: java, jenkins, cross-browser, testng, allure

I have a web application that I'm testing in 2 browsers: chrome and edge. The results of the tests must appear in an Allure Report on a Jenkins server. The problem that I am facing is that Allure only shows the test results on the second browser where the tests ran while ignoring the first browser.

My setup is as follows: A BrowserFactory class that takes care of the browser setup and initialization.

```
public class BrowserFactory {
private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    String browser = System.getProperty("BrowserName");
    if ("edge".equals(browser)) {
        driver = initializeEdgeDriver();
        return driver;
    }
    driver = initializeChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}

public static String getBrowserInfo() {
    return ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserVersion();
}

private static WebDriver initializeChromeDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            Optional.ofNullable(BrowserFactory.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResource("drivers//chromedriver.exe"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Missing driver!")).getPath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--lang=en");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    configureDriver(driver);
    return driver;
}
```

Next is the Page class that has all the general operations that can be made on a given web page. The snippet bellow contains only what is relevant for this topic. I am using ThreadLocal for parallel testing.

```
public class Page {
protected static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static void startBrowser() {
    driver.set(ThreadGuard.protect(BrowserFactory.getDriver()));
}

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
}

public static void closeBrowser() {
    getDriver().close();
    getDriver().quit();
    driver.remove();
}
```

Next is a test class

```
public class TestSomething {
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    Page.startBrowser();
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
    Page.closeBrowser();
}

@Test()
public void retrieveBearerToken() {
    //do some test     
}
```

In Jenkins I'm calling this runner on 2 separate jobs, one for chrome and one for edge, with the following commands:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test something">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="org.evidian.qaautomation.util.testngcustomized.RetryFailedTestListener"/>
</listeners>
<test name="Test something">
<parameter name="BrowserName" value="${BrowserName}"/>
<classes>
<class name="ui.test.TestSomething"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>

test -DsuiteXMLFile=src/main/resources/Runner/test_Something.xml, -DBrowserName=edge
test -DsuiteXMLFile=src/main/resources/Runner/test_Something.xml, -DBrowserName=chrome
```

What am I missing? Is Allure not able to support cross browser testing? Or is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create dynamic test names + manipulate with Allure historyId, browserPrefix() need to implemented by you:

Example:

```
@Story("Your Story Name")
@Test
public void loginStandardUser() {
  updateTestNameForAllure(browserPrefix() + "YourStoryName");
  standardUserActions.loginAction();
}

private void updateTestNameAndHistoryIdForAllure(String newName) {
  Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName(newName));
  String customHistoryId = Utils.generateConsistentHistoryId(newName, getBrowserName());
  Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setHistoryId(customUUID));
}

privat String generateConsistentHistoryId(String newName, String browserName) {
  String baseString = newName + browserName;
  return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(baseString.getBytes()).toString();
}
```

[image]